# Openweather One Call 3.0 deserializeJson() failed with code InvalidInput

Tags: esp32, openweathermap

Good Day! I'm working on N IoT smart irrigation system that uses weather forecast. If the chance of precipitation is 80% or more in an hour, it does not irrigate and so on. How do I get the data from Openweather successfully? it keeps on showing deserializeJson() failed with code InvalidInput
The DHT and Soil moisture does work. [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7QsP.png)

this is how the code looks like[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iyOi.png)

I was expecting the data from openweather or Please note that using one call 3.0 requires a separate subscription

Comment: Please provide your code, not image if you want others to help you.